# Powershell splitting line from output

Tags: powershell, parsing, split

I dabbled here and there with PowerShell but I still need some work. I am trying to take an output from a line of a text file to get ready to use it to migrate to another domain with same user name base. The extract is a group name called "Group-Executives-ronly" and the next set of data is the groups and users in that group called "Group-Executives-ronly"

```
$variable1 = '"Group-Executives-ronly","Group Approvers for accounts;Wilson, Frank fwilson;Jorden, mike mjorden;smith, David dsmith"'
```

I am just displaying result before I actually use this data to do the other work. I would like to get each line printed like so but every iteration of split is not working well for the user name section.

```
Group-Executives-ronly

Group Approvers for accounts
fwilson
mjorden
dsmith
```

I had first broken it up with

```
$group=$variable1.Split('"')\[1\]
$Userslist=$variable1.Split('"')\[3\]
```

Which gave the first array the `Group-Executives-ronly` and the 3rd array `Group Approvers for accounts;Wilson, Frank fwilson;Jorden, mike mjorden;smith, David dsmith`

I did another array for splitting with `;`

```
$Users=$Userslist.Split(';')
```

and that gave me all the group/users split like so

```
Group Approvers for accounts

Wilson, Frank fwilson

Jorden, mike mjorden

smith, David dsmith
```

I like that I got the full group name but I don't want the name of those users, I just need their `UID`, is that possible, am I going at it wrong? The desired output needed is

```
Group Approvers for accounts

fwilson

mjorden

dsmith
```

Comment: This text file where you get line we see in `$variable1`, do you have access to modify the way that text file is exporting the data? Wouldn't it make sense to have it output as Json instead of this string that requires parsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71668721/powershell-splitting-line-from-output#comment126661679_71668721) said.

You're close: from the userlist after splitting in ';', if it contains a ',' then split on space and grab the last item, otherwise just take the whole userlist item.

```
PS /> $variable1 = '"Group-Executives-ronly","Group Approvers for accounts;Wilson, Frank fwilson;Jorden, mike mjorden;smith, David dsmith"'
PS /> $group=$variable1.Split('"')[1]                                                                                                      
PS /> $Userslist=$variable1.Split('"')[3]                                                                                                  
PS /> $Userslist.split(';') | %{if ($_.contains(',')){$_.split(' ')[-1]} else {$_}}                                                        
Group Approvers for accounts
fwilson
mjorden
dsmith
PS />
```